# how to get only hours with am and pm in java script

Tags: javascript

I have written code to get hours with am and pm, but getting wrong time like 13 pm and 14 pm

Expected op - 1 pm, 2pm ...

```js
var d = new Date();
var h1 = d.getHours();
h1 = getTime(h1);

function getTime(number) {
  var strTime = "";
  var ampm = number >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  if (number == 0) {
    strTime = 12 + " am";
  }
  if (number != 0) {
    strTime = number + " " + ampm;
  }
  return strTime;
}

console.log(h1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `strTime = (number % 12) +" "+ ampm;` when `number != 0`. Using modulus operator will give you the correct output as after `12` we need `1`, `2`, ... and so on.

```js
var d = new Date();
var h1 = d.getHours();
h1 = getTime(h1);

function getTime(number) {
  var strTime = "";
  var ampm = number > 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  if (number == 0) {
    strTime = "12 am";
  } else if (number == 12) {
    strTime = "12 pm";
  } else {
    strTime = (number % 12) + " " + ampm;
  }
  return strTime;
}
console.log(h1);
```

Comment: It will result `0 pm`.

Comment: yes at 12 pm its giving 0 pm.

Comment: @krishnamohan It doesn't now. No reason for downvote

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal now instead `12pm` it will show `12am`

Comment: @Durga oops. It seems like I added a wrong condition. It does now :)

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, have simplified the answer, check if it is wrong.